# How can I make vinagre remember my desktop size settings?

Tags: remote-desktop, gnome3

Vinagre, the Gnome Remote Desktop viewer, keeps defaulting to the same desktop size (which is small and annoying, and isn't even my X's desktop size). I can't find anywhere to change these values.

I'm using Lubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `~/.local/share/vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks.xml`. It should contain the default window size as `<width>800</width><height>600</height>`.

My window size is driven by the guest OS. You can however adjust the default `vinagre` scaling options in the above file too.

Comment: I don't actually have any bookmarks, but I'll try making one.